# DateTime Filter AngularJS not Giving Correct Date?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, date, datetime

I am using backend as Tomcat which gives me timestamp as follows :-

`1448966450000` If I use the [website to convert](http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm) this time to datetime it gives me something like below :-

`1448966450000 -> Wed, 02 Dec 47885 00:33:20 GMT`

But when I use a Filter for AngularJS it gives me something like this:-

`{{1448966450000  | date: "MMM dd,yyyy '@' hh:mma"}} -> Dec 01,2015 @ 04:10PM`

I am living at India and according to IST the time which I receive with the filter is pretty wrong. I am not able to understand where the problem lies.

**NOTE: Date Shown by angular is wrong while the former one is the correct one.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Take a look at your timestamp, your site needs timestamp in seconds, but angular filter accepts milliseconds, so you need to multiply your timestamp in filter on 1000, you need to enter *1448966450000000*, not *1448966450000*
2. Check the timezone: add timezone to output format (**Z**)
3. If timezone is not suitable for you, set preferred timezone

   `{{1448966450000  | date: "MMM dd,yyyy '@' hh:mma" : '+0530'}}`

For more information see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: I am still not getting the date as mentioned in the former case. Have a look at this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/69o08c02/3/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/69o08c02/4/ - timezone conversion works, but take a look at your timestamp - it uses milliseconds. I'll edit an answer

Answer (score 0):

The timestamp you are using is in milliseconds since 1/1/1970
The angular filter does it right.
The website you test it wants the timestamp in seconds.

Comment: Actually thats not the case. You can find the conversion is the correct date while the angular one is wrong. Sorry I would update the same.

Comment: Angular expressions are a subset of javascript plus the pipe operator. In your filter expression, 144896645000 is interpreted as the time since 1/1/1970 in milliseconds. This is the javascript default. Not, as you expect, as a unix timestamp. Sorry, but angular does it right.